# Can I filter search results by using the segment in ExpressionEngine?

Tags: search, expressionengine

I'm trying to get a word to read either singular or plural in expressionengine based on the amount of entries with a certain variable, but not having any luck. Here's what it is currently:

```
exp:channel:entries channel="specialist" dynamic="no" search:sp_specialty="={segment_2}" }
  {if total_entries <= 1 }
    OUR SPECIALIST
  {if:else}
    OUR SPECIALISTS
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Can I match a search using the segment value? Right now it's not working. Easier way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly is not working? The conditional or the search/filer?

Comment: Think it was my brain not working, I can search by segment_2, but my variables weren't matching. I'll post the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="specialist"
    dynamic="no"
    search:sp_specialty="={segment_2}"
}
    {if count == '1'}
        {if total_results == '1'}
            OUR SPECIALIST
        {if:else}
            OUR SPECIALISTS
        {/if}
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

- You want to use `total_results` not `total_entries`.
- Checking for 1 or fewer results is redundant as the channel entries tag will output nothing if there's no results (unless you use an `{if no_results}` tag pair).

Comment: any to get this method to prevent displaying the "Our Specialists" multiple times? if I add limit="1" my total_results comes out to 1. I'm trying to add a header to the list that is either singular or plural. Seems like this is more difficult to pull of than it should be...

Comment: Sure, just add an `{if count == '1'}` wrapper. To be honest we're probably at the point where it makes more sense to use the query module, but I've revised my code sample and it should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I'm going to look more into the query module, but this does the trick.